# How install the recommended version for the ixgbevf driver on a EC2 Instance running Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, kernel, amazon-ec2

I did `modinfo ixgbevf` on an updated Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS instance created from the official AMI ami-f4cc1de2 and got:

```
...
version:        2.12.1-k
...
```

AWS doc state that *the recommended version 2.14.2*, which have the latest bug fixes.

I tried Install the *linux-image-4.4.0-1009-aws* because read in some places that could have a newest version and nothing.

Beside the installation from the source, do I have another option to keep that kernel module updated as AWS recommend?

Answer (score 2):

The same doc also gives you the procedure on how to use it with dkms: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sriov-networking.html#enhanced-networking-ubuntu

There's one catch, you will have to modify the downloaded driver to not throw an error on the "bignumber-aws".

Comment: Correct, but i wanna avoid install it from source, is important for me stick with the Ubuntu package manager and the "official" .deb packages. Seem that such thing is not possible at the moment right?

Comment: Any news ? Any new info ?